# New tag request

Tags: feature-request, tags

Please can we create a GDPR tag as this may be useful in the lead up to May 2018 where the regulations will come into affect: https://ico.org.uk/for-organisations/data-protection-reform/overview-of-the-gdpr/

Comment: It looks like the existing tag [Tag:eu-cookie-law] might still cover this new regulation.

Comment: Perhaps in part as cookies are covered by the GDPR, however I think the topic is much wider than cookies alone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I created the [GDPR](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gdpr) tag, added Wiki content for it, and added the tag to your related question:  [GDPR compliant contact form](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/110724/gdpr-compliant-contact-form).

This new regulation covers [Personal Data](http://europa.eu/rapid/press-release_IP-12-46_en.htm?locale=en) for all individuals within the European Union (EU):

> Personal data is any information relating to an individual, whether it
>   relates to his or her private, professional or public life. It can be
>   anything from a name, a photo, an email address, bank details, your
>   posts on social networking websites, your medical information, or your
>   computer's IP address. The EU Charter of Fundamental Rights says that
>   everyone has the right to personal data protection in all aspects of
>   life: at home, at work, whilst shopping, when receiving medical
>   treatment, at a police station or on the Internet.

It will take effect on May 25th, 2018.